How Can I Get Beamer to Format a Sequence of Broken TOC Pages Consistently Using the Package tcolorbox?
I would like to have beamer generate table of contents (TOC) page frames which may be broken into  several slides should it be case that one slide does not provide enough space to hold the entire TOC. I am exploring the use of the tcolorbox to break TOC frames. However, I am not able to have the broken frames formatted consistently in terms of:

Setting the same amount of space above the title in each frame.
Setting same amount of separation between the title and the rest of the contents of each frame.

The following images show what I get from my MWE which is given below. There is an obvious difference between the space at the top of the first slide and the space at the top of the other two slides. Similarly, the spacing between the title and the rest of the contents of the first slide differs from the corresponding spacing in the second and the third slides.



I request for help in tackling the stated problem. Thanks in advance to all.
The MWE that generated the slides:
 \documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[most,many]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usetheme{default}
 % 
 \makeatletter
 % 
 \newtcolorbox{tocframebox}{
    height = \dimexpr(\paperheight-\beamer@leftmargin),
    width  = \dimexpr(\paperwidth-(\beamer@leftmargin+\beamer@rightmargin)),
    before = \vfill,
    after = \vfill,
    halign = flush left,
    valign = top,
    breakable,
    break at=\dimexpr(\paperheight-(14pt+14pt)),
    top = 1.5em,
    boxrule=0pt,
    frame empty,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left  =0pt,
    right =0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    opacityfill=0,
    title = \usebeamertemplate*{part toc title},
    title after break = \usebeamertemplate*{part toc title continuation},
 }
 % 
 \setbeamerfont{part toc title}{series=\mdseries,size=\large}
 \setbeamercolor{part toc title}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
 % 
 \def\partTocHeader{
    \usebeamerfont{part toc title}
    {
       \usebeamercolor[fg]{part name}
       \partname~\insertromanpartnumber\par
    }
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{part title}
    \insertpart\ignorespaces
 }
 % 
 \setbeamercolor{part name}{bg=,fg=black}
 \defbeamertemplate*{part toc title}{hoo}{
    \partTocHeader
 }
 \defbeamertemplate*{part toc title continuation}{hoo}{
    \partTocHeader\ \insertcontinuationtext
 }
 \defbeamertemplate*{section in toc}{hoo}{
    \usebeamercolor{section in toc}
    \usebeamerfont{section in toc}
    \inserttocsectionnumber.\hskip 1ex\inserttocsection
 }
 \defbeamertemplate*{part toc page}{hoo}{
    \tableofcontents[
       part = \value{part},
       sectionstyle = show/show,
       subsectionstyle = hide/hide/hide,
       subsubsectionstyle = hide/hide/hide
    ]
 }
 \AtBeginPart{
    \begin{frame}[plain,t,allowframebreaks]
    \begin{tocframebox}
       \usebeamertemplate*{part toc page}
    \end{tocframebox}
    \end{frame}
 }
 
 \makeatother
 % 
 \begin{document}
        
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 % 
    \part{Table of Contents}
 
    \section[Sec 1]{Section 1 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 1 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}
 
    \section[Sec 2]{Section 2 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 2 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}     
 
    \section[Sec 3]{Section 3 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 3 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}
 
    \section[Sec 4]{Section 4 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 4 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}
 
    \section[Sec 5]{Section 5 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 5 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}
 
    \section[Sec 6]{Section 6 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 6 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}
 
    \section[Sec 7]{Section 7 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 7 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}
 
    \section[Sec 8]{Section 8 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 8 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}
 
    \section[Sec 9]{Section 9 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 9 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}
 
    \section[Sec 10]{Section 10 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 10 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}     
 
    \section[Sec 11]{Section 11 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 11 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}     
 
    \section[Sec 12]{Section 12 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 12 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}     
 
    \section[Sec 13]{Section 13 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 13 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}     
 
    \section[Sec 14]{Section 14 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 14 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}     
 
    \section[Sec 15]{Section 15 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 15 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}
 
    \section[Sec 16]{Section 16 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 16 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}     
 
    \section[Sec 17]{Section 17 Title}
 
    \begin{frame}{Section 17 Overview}
       The overview.
    \end{frame}     
 % 
 \end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thanks @Mensch.

Using a tcolorbox seems unnecessary:
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most,many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginPart{{
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
  \setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=structure.fg}
  \setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\large}
  \setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
  \begin{frame}[plain,t,allowframebreaks=0.5]
  \frametitle{Part \@Roman{\thepart}}
  \framesubtitle{Table of Contents~\vphantom{(cont.)}\ifnum\insertcontinuationcount>1\relax(cont.)\vspace*{.75\topsep}\fi
  }
  \tableofcontents
  \end{frame}
}}
\makeatother

% 
\begin{document}
% 
  \part{Table of Contents}
  

  \section[Sec 1]{Section 1 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 1 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}

  \section[Sec 2]{Section 2 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 2 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}     

  \section[Sec 3]{Section 3 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 3 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}

  \section[Sec 4]{Section 4 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 4 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}

  \section[Sec 5]{Section 5 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 5 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}

  \section[Sec 6]{Section 6 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 6 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}

  \section[Sec 7]{Section 7 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 7 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}

  \section[Sec 8]{Section 8 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 8 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}

  \section[Sec 9]{Section 9 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 9 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}

  \section[Sec 10]{Section 10 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 10 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}     

  \section[Sec 11]{Section 11 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 11 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}     

  \section[Sec 12]{Section 12 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 12 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}     

  \section[Sec 13]{Section 13 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 13 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}     

  \section[Sec 14]{Section 14 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 14 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}     

  \section[Sec 15]{Section 15 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 15 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}

  \section[Sec 16]{Section 16 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 16 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}     

  \section[Sec 17]{Section 17 Title}

  \begin{frame}{Section 17 Overview}
     The overview.
  \end{frame}     
% 
\end{document}





Thanks a lot @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for your quick and illuminating answer to my question. Your solution is obviously smarter than mine. May I ask one more question. Would it be possible to modify your solution such that, in addition to breaking the TOC frame, the contents of the broken frame could also be paused?

@HOO framebreaks and overlays are incompatible.

Thanks a lot once more, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.
